# Apache-airflow 2.5.0: How to utilize config JSON in Python VirtualEnv Operator

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2, directed-acyclic-graphs

my Apache airflow version is 2.5.0.

I want to access and use the values of config json set on triggering the DAG. I have tried the following given solutions to the issue but None of them worked.

The config is ritten in the configuration json section :
{"conf1": "test"}

I want to acces the value of conf1 in my Python VirtualEnv Operator.

config JSON: {"conf1": "test"}

- using **context
  `context['dag_run'].conf['conf1']`
  ***error: this gave the error that there was no "dag_run" in context***
- using Jinja Templete: ***did not work. dag_run not defined***
  `dag_config = {{ dag_run }}`
  `dag_config = {{ dag_run.conf['conf1'] }}`
  `dag_config = "{{ dag_run }}"`
- DAG params: ***Could create default params BUT could not access them in the python operator***
  `params={"conf1": ""}`
- Installing jinja2 to get Template: Error. "dag_run" not defined.
   `tm = Template("Hello {{ dag_run }}")`
  `msg = tm.render(dag_run=dag_run)`
   `tm = Template("Hello {{ dag_run.conf['conf1'] }}")`
  `msg = tm.render(dag_run=dag_run)`

Expectation:

To get the value 'test' in the functions under Python VirtualEnv Operator in a varaible that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an upstream task as a helper to feed the context variable into the PythonVirtualEnvOperator:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
import pendulum

with DAG(
    dag_id='test_venv',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    params={
        "param1": "default_value",
    },
    render_template_as_native_obj=True # To prevent all params to be converted to strings
):

    @task(
        templates_dict={"my_config" : "{{ params.param1 }}"}
    )
    def get_param(**kwargs):
        return kwargs["templates_dict"]["my_config"]

    @task.virtualenv(
        task_id="virtualenv_python",
        requirements=["numpy"],
    )
    def python_virtual_env_operator_task(my_config):
        print(my_config)

    python_virtual_env_operator_task(get_param())
```

You will also want to double check that `core.dag_run_conf_overrides_params` is set to True.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @TjaniF (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188617/9286461)
is good, however, it will start 2 tasks instead of 1, which may be slower (e.g. on a kubernetes cluster, where each task has to initialise in a separate worker, which has considerable start-up time).

I suggest using template references. E.g.

```py
@task.virtualenv(requirements=["colorama"])
def venv_task(params=None, ts=None, dic=None):
    print(f'params: {params}')
    print(f'ts: {ts}')

    print(f'dic: {dic}')


@dag(
    schedule=None,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
def test_virtualenv():
    venv_task(dic={
        "dag_id": "{{ ti.dag_id }}",
        "task_id": "{{ ti.task_id }}",
        "execution_date": "{{ ti.execution_date }}",
        "run_id": "{{ ti.run_id }}",
    })
```